# How to install Steel Storm from source?

Tags: source-code

There is no deb package. How can I install it anyway?
http://www.steel-storm.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install it. Just download the tar.gz file, unpack it somewhere and double click on steelstorm or steelstorm64 (depends on your architecture) in it's directory.

Comment: Hmm I thought I need deb files everytime ... This is confusing me

Comment: deb files is for installing software packages, like installers on windows, they're making necessary config files, launchers to menus, etc. But you can also run programs by pre-complied files, like exe files and portables on windows.